# How to download a single webpage for offline viewing?

Tags: html, curl, web, wget

I would like to download a single page for offline viewing. This means that all of the images, fonts, and css of the webpage must be downloaded.
I DO NOT want to download an entire website, just a single webpage.

I have tried curl, and wget with no success..maybe I don't know how to properly use them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you would grab just one page w/ all assets:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p url
```

More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget